# _trackEvent() method in Google analytic. and what method in firebase analytics?

Tags: angularjs, firebase, google-analytics

Earlier we used the Google analytics in our application, in which we used the .trackEvent() method which use to record user interaction with website elements. Now we migrate to firebase analytics, then which method is used to record user interaction with our application.

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/events?platform=web ?

Comment: Did you look up the firebase documentation or tutorials ?